# How to prove such a relationship?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a function $S(x,y)$ which satisfies the following PDE
$$\frac{\partial S(x,y)}{\partial y}=-H\left(x,\frac{\partial S(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)$$
where the known function $H(x,z)=x^2+xz+z^2+\frac{1}{x-\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta-x}$. Here $\alpha<x<\beta$.

> Can we prove that when $x\to\alpha$ or $x\to\beta$, $\dfrac{\partial S(x,y)}{\partial x}\to\infty$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Voliar Sorry, but I miss the condition $\alpha<\beta$.

Comment: Do you know something else about the solution $S(x,y)$? Maybe it has some special form? For example, if $S(x,y)= F(x) G(y)$, then it is possible to prove what you want.

Comment: @Voliar Yes, some extra conditions are necessary. So if we know $S(x,y)=F(x)G(x)$ as you mentioned, can you show the proof? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume, without loss of generality, that $x \to \alpha$ (keep in mind that $x \to \alpha+0$). Then there are three possible limits for $H(x,S'_x)$ as $x \to \alpha$:

1) $H(x, S'_x) \to +\infty$;

2) $H(x, S'_x) \to C$, where $C$ is some constant;

3) $H(x, S'_x) \to -\infty$.

It is not hard to show, that 2) and 3) are impossible. Indeed, assume first that $|S'_x| < C_1 < +\infty$ for all $x \in [\alpha, \beta)$. Then, of course, $H(x, S'_x) \to +\infty$ (just because all the terms, except $\frac{1}{x-\alpha}$, are bounded).
If now $S'_x \to \pm \infty$ (the sign of $\infty$ is irrelevant), then
$$
x S'_x + (S'_x)^2 = S'_x (x + S'_x) \to +\infty,
$$
and also $\frac{1}{x-\alpha} \to +\infty$. Hence, we get that only 1) is possible.

Now, we assume that $S(x,y) = F(x) G(y)$.
Since 
$$
H(x, S'_x) \equiv H(x, F'(x) G(y)) \to +\infty,
$$
we get (from the equation) that
$$
S'_y = F(x) G'(y) \to -\infty \quad \text{as } x \to \alpha.
$$
However, this implies that $F(x) \to -\infty$, since $G'(y)$ is a fixed constant for each fixed $y$.

But, this implies that $F'(x) \to -\infty$, since $F(x)$ is continuously differentiable on $(\alpha, \beta)$.

Indeed, if we suppose that $|F'(x)| < C_1 < +\infty$ for all $x \in [\alpha, \beta)$, then by, for example, the mean value theorem we get that $|F(\alpha)| < C_2 < +\infty$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, $F'(x) \to -\infty$, and, consequently, $S'_x = F'(x) G(y) \to -\infty$.

Comment: If I'm wrong somewhere, let me know, please.

Comment: Your proof is great! But I have question that how do you know $F(x)\to-\infty$ (why not $F(x)\to+\infty$ since we do not know the sign of $G'(y)$) from $S'_y=F(x)G'(y)\to-\infty$ as $x\to\alpha$? And I also would like to know why $F(x)\to-\infty$ implies $F(x)'\to-\infty$? Thanks.

Comment: @user143763 Oops! You are right. $F'(x)$ can tend to $+\infty$, too. However, in this case we have absolutely same conclusion.

Comment: @user143763 Let us apply the Mean value theorem. Since $F(x)$ is continuously differentiable on $(\alpha, \beta)$, for any $x, z \in (\alpha, \beta)$ there exists $c \in (\alpha, \beta)$, such that $$|F(x) - F(z)| \leq |x - z| |F'(c)|.$$  If now we assume that $|F'(x)| < C_1$ for all $x \in [\alpha, \beta)$, then, tending $x$ to $\alpha$ and fixing any $z \in (\alpha, \beta)$, we get $$|F(x) - F(z)| < C_2,$$ however, it is impossible since $F(x) \to \infty$ and $F(z)$ is some fixed constant.

Comment: Yes, but it seems that your proof leads to the conclusion: $F'(x)\to\infty$ for all $x\in[\alpha,\beta)$, not only when $x\to\alpha$?

Comment: @user143763 Of course, not. The mean value theorem postulates the existence of $c \in (\alpha, \beta)$, for which the estimation holds. Really, $c$ depends on $x$. And it is not hard to see that $c \to \alpha$, as $x \to \alpha$. (otherwise, it will contradicts the continuous differentiability of $F$).

Comment: Yes, now I well understand your proof. Thanks so much!